# Javascript prompt box with only OK button

Tags: javascript, customization, prompt, cancel-button

Is it possible to customize a javascript prompt box to have only OK button? In my PhoneGap app I  need a box just like normal javascript alert that has only he option to click OK, but it should also have a text field for user input.

And yes, I know it is not the most user-friendly way to force the user to have only option to click OK and not cancel, but in my case it is exactly the thing I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

No. `alert` and `confirm` dialogs cannot be styled or modified in any way through JavaScript. They are part of the underlying operating system.

You could use one of the many existing lightbox scripts, such as the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).